# How do I remove single boot ubuntu and install windows 8 from usb on surface pro?

Tags: 14.04

So I bought a surface pro off ebay that has ubuntu 14.04 loaded with GRUB. I'm wondering how I go about uninstalling ubuntu and GRUB to allow me to boot my windows installer from USB?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that?!

Comment: Have fun with license keys ;) But yeah, this is about installing windows, and has nothing to do with ubuntu, as you don't "uninstall" you just delete partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how surface pro booting works, but you just boot the ubuntu installer (the usb or whatever you used) and delete all partitions on the disk, then boot the windows installer.

P.S. this really isn't an ubuntu question, it is more a question of just installing windows. Sorry to see you go, and please return some time from the land of closed source software!